# Which Kubernetes Object manages Job and CronJob workloads?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, jobs, replicaset, kubernetes-cronjob

All Jobs and CronJobs ultimately run as Pods. Apart from stand alone pods other pods are managed by deployments/replicasets. But for Job and CronJob I don't see any deployment or ReplicaSet though the job/cronjob pods have same nomenclature as of a RS managed POD like [deployment.replicaset-name]-XXX.

Who manages these workloads?

Answer (score 0):

A Job is something like you would run only a Pod, it's not managed by a Deployment/ReplicaSet.

From the Documentation:

> A Job creates one or more Pods and will continue to retry execution of
> the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

The same is valid for the CronJob, it simply executes a Job at a defined time.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes Jobs can fail and a new Pod might be scheduled to run the Job. This is managed by the [Job Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/#control-via-api-server):

> The Job controller is an example of a Kubernetes built-in controller. Built-in controllers manage state by interacting with the cluster API server.

> Job is a Kubernetes resource that runs a Pod, or perhaps several Pods, to carry out a task and then stop.

> (Once scheduled, Pod objects become part of the desired state for a kubelet).

> When the Job controller sees a new task it makes sure that, somewhere in your cluster, the kubelets on a set of Nodes are running the right number of Pods to get the work done. The Job controller does not run any Pods or containers itself. Instead, the Job controller tells the API server to create or remove Pods. Other components in the control plane act on the new information (there are new Pods to schedule and run), and eventually the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

> Which Kubernetes Object manages Job and CronJob workloads?

Let me start with [Cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/):

> A *CronJob* creates [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) on a repeating schedule.

Take into account, that cronjob is a relatively new feature. It has been available since version 1.21 (stable).
Going further:

> A Job creates one or more Pods and will continue to retry execution of the Pods until a specified number of them successfully terminate. As pods successfully complete, the Job tracks the successful completions. When a specified number of successful completions is reached, the task (ie, Job) is complete. Deleting a Job will clean up the Pods it created. Suspending a Job will delete its active Pods until the Job is resumed again.

This is all managed by [Job Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/#controller-pattern), which was mentioned very well by [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213269/jonas).

However, if you are using a dedicated solution, e.g. GKE, you can get [additional information](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/jobs#:%7E:text=Jobs%20are%20represented%20by%20Kubernetes,Pods%20completed%20their%20tasks%20successfully.):

> In GKE, a **Job** is a controller object that represents a finite task. Jobs differ from other controller objects in that Jobs manage the task as it runs to completion, rather than managing an ongoing desired state (such as the total number of running Pods).

> In GKE, there are two types of Jobs:
>
> - **Non-parallel Job:**  A Job which creates only one Pod (which is re-created if the Pod terminates unsuccessfully), and which is completed when the Pod terminates successfully.
> - **Parallel jobs with a completion count:**  A Job that is completed when a certain number of Pods terminate successfully. You specify the desired number of completions using the  `completions`  field.

See also:

- [Nice article about kubernetes controllers](https://www.fairwinds.com/blog/kubernetes-controllers)
- [Jobs & Cronjobs in Kubernetes Cluster](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/jobs-cronjobs-in-kubernetes-cluster-d0e872e3c8c8)
- [Kubernetes by example - jobs](https://www.kubernetesbyexample.com/en/concept/jobs)